# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'addNewMessage'

Tags: python, class, user-interface, methods, tkinter

I am facing this problem. I am pretty new both with threads and GUIs in py and this is why i can't get out of it. 
Basically i have this class:

```
class receiving(threading.Thread): #thread class
    #init and other methods
    def run(self):
    data = self.sock.recv(1024) #sock is the socket on which the 'run' method as to listen on
    UserIF.main.addNewMessage(data) #with this line i want to pass the 'data' variable to the 'addNewMessage' method
```

That listen on a socket and returns a string and i have to write this string into a tkinter 'Text' object in this class:

```
class UserIF():
    def main(self):
        #some code
        messages = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
        messages.grid(column=5, row=4)
        def addNewMessage(string):
            messages.insert(string)
```

I am trying a sort of 'go to' that i know doesn't exist in python.

Comment: You didn't pass `self` as an argument in `def addNewMessage(string):` but I'm not convinced you need nested functions. `tkinter` is not a strong point for me.

Comment: @roganjosh it's not tkinter the real problem, it's how can i pass the 'data' variable from the run method of the thread class to the main method of the UserIF class to sort of print it let's say.

Answer (score 1):

Why to even use nested functions? just create the `addNewMessage` function on the same identation as the `main` function, don't forget to add the `self` default argument before `string`. Then `UserIF.addNewMessage(data)` in the `run` function should work.

```
class receiving(threading.Thread): #thread class
    #init and other methods
    def run(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(1024)
        UserIF.addNewMessage(data)

class UserIF():
    def main(self):
        #some code
        self.messages = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
        self.messages.grid(column=5, row=4)

    def addNewMessage(self, string):
        self.messages.insert(string)
```

Alternatively you could create a staticmethod if you won't need to use the `self`.

```
@staticmethod
def addNewMessage(string):
    #The next two lines I'm not sure if they are needed.
    messages = tk.Text(master=window, height=10, width=30)
    messages.grid(column=5, row=4)
    #This should work now
    messages.insert(string)
```

Comment: But then the 'messages' Text field won't be inside the 'window' frame because it is initialized in the main method

Comment: It obviously says: "Unresolved reference to 'window'"

Comment: then just pass the window object to the addNewMessage function, you could do that converting it to a class variable I guess, see my edit. Can't guess more without seeing the entire code.